# Left/Center/Right references to subfigures

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I have a figure with three subfigures shown in the code sample below.  How can I change the reference to a subfigure so that I have Figure 1 (left), Figure 1 (center), and Figure 1 (right) instead of figure 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3?  Also, in the caption I would like to it to have a general caption, then in the same paragraph have (left) left's caption (center) center's caption (right) right's caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
\label{fig:left}
\includegraphics[width=2.5in,height=2.5in]{img1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=2.5in,height=2.5in]{img2}
\label{fig:center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=2.5in,height=2.5in]{img3}
\label{fig:right}
\end{minipage}
\caption{
    Blah blah blah.  
    \ref{fig:left} blah blah.   
    \ref{fig:center} blah blah.   
    \ref{fig:right} blah blah.
}
\label{fig:all}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't include any captions for each of the figures, yet you say you want `Figure 1 (left)`, `Figure 1 (center)` and `Figure 1 (right)`. Is this correct... you want these captions? Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? Why don't you just type `\caption{Blah blah blah. (left) blah blah. (center) blah blah. (right) blah blah.}`?

Comment: I'd simply write the caption as `\caption{Blah blah. Left: blahleft. Center: blahcenter. Right: blahright.}`

Comment: That's basically how I've done it right now, but it would be nice to be able to reference the left/center/right pictures within a paragraph.

Comment: I've sometimes done this by using \label for the overall figure, which presents the three subfigures as (a), (b), and (c).  Then, when I reference the left figure in the text, I would use \ref{fg:figlabel}a.  Correspondingly, \ref{fg:figlabel}b for the middle and \ref{fg:figlabel}c for the right figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows, a new numbering system called `\lcr` is defined (which works the same way as `\arabic`, `\alph`, etc. do) that associates "left" to "1", "centre" to "2", and "right" to "3".

The `prettyref` package is then used to customise the cross-referencing to either of the three "subfigures". Note that `\phantomsubcaption` must be used in order to create an anchor for `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\lcr#1{\expandafter\@lcr\csname c@#1\endcsname}% LaTeX
\def\@lcr#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0%
    \@ctrerr% 
  \else\ifnum#1=1%
      left%
    \else\ifnum#1=2%
       center%
     \else\ifnum#1=3%
        right%
      \else
        \@ctrerr%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure~(\lcr{subfigure})}

\usepackage{prettyref}
\newrefformat{subfiglcr}{Figure~\ref{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path[draw=red,fill=red!20] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \phantomsubcaption \label{subfiglcr:left}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path[draw=green,fill=green!20] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \phantomsubcaption \label{subfiglcr:center}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path[draw=blue,fill=blue!20] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \phantomsubcaption \label{subfiglcr:right}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Three squares. Left: red. Center: green. Right: blue.}
    \label{fig:all}
\end{figure*}

\prettyref{subfiglcr:left} shows a typical example of red square;
\prettyref{subfiglcr:center} shows a particularly interesting specimen of green square,
while \prettyref{subfiglcr:right} shows a common and rather unremarkable blue square.

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this example, the `tikz` package is used instead of the `graphicx` package (used by the OP), in order to generate some placeholder pictures.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to make the change specific only to a particular Figure, you can modify @jub0bs answer and use:
     `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\lcr{subfigure}}` in the begging of the figure

```
\begin{figure}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\lcr{subfigure}}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}

    \centering\large A
    \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \centering\large B
    \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \centering\large C
    \subcaption{Yet another}\label{fig:1c}
 \end{minipage}
   \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
 \end{figure}

 Figure~\ref{fig:1a}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\lcr#1{\expandafter\@lcr\csname c@#1\endcsname}% LaTeX
\def\@lcr#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0%
    \@ctrerr% 
  \else\ifnum#1=1%
      left%
    \else\ifnum#1=2%
       center%
     \else\ifnum#1=3%
        right%
      \else
        \@ctrerr%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure~(\lcr{subfigure})}

\usepackage{prettyref}
\newrefformat{subfiglcr}{Figure~\ref{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\lcr{subfigure}}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}

    \centering\large A
    \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \centering\large B
    \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \centering\large C
    \subcaption{Yet another}\label{fig:1c}
 \end{minipage}
   \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
 \end{figure}

 Figure~\ref{fig:1a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentlcass as well as the relevant packages that are needed for your code to successfully compile. Did you use `\lcr` from jub0bs' answer? It might be worth mentioning that as well.

Comment: Yeah, it is a copy/ paste