# Inadvertent effect of figure numbering style change

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

I need to insert **(above)** or **(below)** between some figure numbers and the following colon, to produce, e.g., **Table 0.1 (above):** instead of the more usual **Table 0.1:** (there’s a good typographic reason).

What is a sensible way of doing this?  My method—redefining `\thefigure`—has the unintended consequence of adding **(above)** and **(below)** to the output of `\ref` too.  I need `\ref` to output just the number, e.g., **0.1** in the example below.

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

Calling the figure number ``0.1'' also summons ``(above)'':

\verb|\ref{label}| = \ref{label}

\begin{figure}
.\\
..\\
...\\
....
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure} (above)}    
\caption{This is the caption\label{label}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73043/left-center-right-references-to-subfigures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure the caption package will have hooks that let you do it easily, but one can do it with basic latex: The command that provides for the text surrounding the number in the caption is `\fnum@figure` for figures and `\fnum@table` for tables. The default is essentially `\figurename~\thefigure`. You just want to add `~(above)` to that

```
\begin{figure}
.\\
..\\
...
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure\nobreakspace(above)}
\makeatother
\caption{This is the caption\label{label}}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

A mild alternative to Dan's answer, inserts content based on a user-level command into the `\@makecaption` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{topnumber}{3}% Just for this example
\usepackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\makeatletter
% \.patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xpatchcmd*{\@makecaption}{#1}{#1\@bove@below}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{\belowcaptionskip}{\belowcaptionskip\gdef\@bove@below{}}{\typeout{success}}{}
\def\@bove@below{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\floataddition}{s m}{%
  \def\@bove@below{#2}% Add above/below
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\xdef\@bove@below{~\@bove@below}}%
    {\xdef\@bove@below{~(\@bove@below)}}% Add brackets when NOT using *
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\verb|\ref{label1}| = \ref{label1}

\begin{figure}
  \centering\rule{.8\linewidth}{20pt}
  \floataddition{above}
  \caption{This is the caption\label{label1}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering\rule{.8\linewidth}{20pt}
  \caption{This is the caption\label{label2}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \floataddition*{below}
  \caption{This is the caption\label{label3}}
  \centering\rule{.8\linewidth}{20pt}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\floataddition[*]{<stuff>}` is limited to the scope of the float (by default, since the float forms a group) and inserts `(<stuff>)` after the number. The starred version does not print the parentheses.