# subfigure with custom references (like an equation's \tag)

Tags: captions, subfloats

Is there a way to customize the display of a subfigure reference like a `\tag` command does in an equation.

For example, the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\exfigure#1{\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}\path[draw=#1,fill=#1!20] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \exfigure{red}
    \phantomsubcaption \label{subfig1}
    % \tag{\figurenum(red)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \exfigure{green}
    \phantomsubcaption \label{subfig2}
    % \tag{\figurenum(green)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \exfigure{blue}
    \phantomsubcaption \label{subfig3}
    % \tag{\figurenum(blue)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Three squares. Left: red. Center: green. Right: blue.}
  \label{fig:all}
\end{figure}

In \cref{fig:all}, we have three subfigures \cref{subfig1}
\cref{subfig2} and \cref{subfig3}.
\end{document}
```

In this example, `cref` displays

> In fig. 1, we have three subfigures fig. 1a fig. 1b and fig. 1c.

I would like to instead have

> In fig. 1, we have three subfigures fig. 1(red) fig. 1(green) and fig. 1(blue).

By customizing the labels as the invalid commented statement do, i.e., using something like `\tag{\figurenum(red)}`

I saw an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73043/left-center-right-references-to-subfigures) for a similar problem(where I took the MWE from). That answer has a more global solution for all subfigures and is based on the placement of the subfigures (or their number). It also does not use `cleveref` which I prefer to use.

Is there a way to customize the label for each figure/subfigure separately?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423580/how-to-label-subset-of-figures-as-subfigures-and-include-an-overall-caption

Comment: That is actually exactly what I need! A command like `\def\figtag#1{\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{#1}}` seems to work flawlessly. Thanks! If you write an answer I will accept it, otherwise I can answer my own question based on this comment.

Comment: Hmm... It is difficult to customize the reference and subref formats if the label is set this way.

Comment: I have to admit that redefining \thesubfigure is the simplest way to accomplish the task.  The best part is that the effects are limited to one figure.